# SQLite - Can I send a database file with application?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Pretty simple question, can I send a already created database (a file, for instance) with my application?
Or do I have to create it inside my application?

Comment: yes no prob. we do it all the time :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do both. Either create on 1st launch or copy preconfigured database from assets.

For the latter option (which is basically significantly faster if you need your database to be pre-populated) you can use [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to do all the job.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a "workaround" or people really prefers to create database this way?

Answer (score 0):

you may put it into the `assets/` folder and copy into the SQLite on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps include an SQLite database in the assets folder, and copy it when the app is launched.